# "Loose" inter process communication

Tags: linux, ipc

I have two programs (namely dwm and slock). I want to trigger a function in dwm depending on events happening in slock and vice versa. The requirement is that both should be independent and run without the other program and also work together.

What is the easiest and/or the best (most efficient) IPC solution/method?

Comment: can each program discover the other's process ID and send a signal?

Comment: @Milag yes they can. Bur how do I attach payload to a signal?

Comment: a signal could trigger activity in the other proc; if you need a block of data as well, maybe use shared memory or R/W with a named pipe

Comment: @Milag doesn't shared memory need both processes to run? Slock is not allways running.

Comment: by expecting either proc to exist or not, each proc could attempt to create, attach, or both, handling any errors

Comment: @Milag thanks. I'll try it tomorrow.

Comment: A Unix domain socket is not hard to set up.  Examples abound.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done it like Milag sugested in the comments:

> a signal could trigger activity in the other proc; if you need a block of data as well, maybe use shared memory or R/W with a named pipe